# C++ Multiple Object monitor on timeout

Tags: c++, asynchronous, timer, asynccallback

I am working on a solution where need to create around 30k objects for a class. Some actions are performed and it waits for some response. The object need to be monitor for timeout to check if response was not received and timeout happens. upon timeout another action is performed. Each object will have their own timer value set and monitor.

Have tried to use boost::asio async method but the performance degrades for such large number of objects.

What would be a better approach here and if someone can point to some available source or library

Comment: Well... you could just have "one" timeout set for the next object to timeout.  Then keep a sorted list of timeouts --- when one timeout triggers, set the timeout for the top of the list.

Comment: thanks a lot...working on same model. but is there something already available that can be reused